# quality of approximation of Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, approximation, stochastic-integrals

I am doing project in economics and I need to calculate the Ito integral:

$$\int_0^T f(X_t)dW_t$$

where $f$ is differentiable $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X_t$ is a diffusion $dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t, X_t)dW_t$

The problem is I don't know exactly the function $f$ but I have an approximation to it $f^*$. I use Euler discretization to calculate the integral.

Lets say $\sup|f - f^*| < \epsilon$.

Is there any way to bound the error ?:

$$\int_0^T f(X_t)dW_t - \int_0^T (f^*)(X_t)dW_t$$

Do I need to impose some constraints on $f, \mu$ or $\sigma$?

What I can do:

$$\int_0^T (f(X_t) - (f^*)(X_t))dW_t  = \sum_{i = 0}^N (f(X_{t_i}) - (f^*)(X_{t_i}))(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})$$

$$\sum_{i = 0}^N (f(X_{t_i}) - (f^*)(X_{t_i}))(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}}) < \epsilon \sum_{i = 0}^N(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})$$

Which is the sum of normal random variables and then I can write some inequality for the tails. Can I do anything better?

Comment: Under certain conditions the $p$-norm is bounded above by $\epsilon \sqrt{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}} T^{1/2 - 1/p}$ for $p\geq 2$.

Comment: @StefanPerko shouldn't there be some probabilistic inequality, because Ito integral is a random variable?

Comment: I'm taking about the $p$-norm, i.e. $\|X\|_p = (\mathbb E |X|^p)^{1/p}$. Pathwise I don't know anything that can be said of the top of my head.

Comment: The equality is generally not true. There is convergence as $N\to \infty$, but only in probability, not pathwise.

Comment: @StefanPerko yes, you are right

Comment: @StefanPerko can you please show me how to obtain the bound for $\mathcal{p}$ norm?

Comment: I wrote an answer. My bound was slightly incorrect, see the answer.

Comment: @StefanPerko thank you very much! I need some time to digest the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\mathbb E\int_0^T |f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)|^p\,dt < T\epsilon^p < \infty, p\geq 2$$

Because of this $(\int_0^t f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)\,dW)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale and there are certain inequalities for moments of martingales (e.g. cf. Karatzas & Shreve "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" - 'Martingale Moment Inequalities [Millar (1968), Novikov
(1971)]).

Reformulated for a problem one of these inequalities says if $\mathbb E \int_0^T |X_t|^p \,dt < \infty$, then 
$$\| \int_0^T X_t\,dW_t \|_p \leq \sqrt{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}}T^{\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 p} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |X_t|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}, p\geq 2.$$

I'll provide a sketch of the proof:

Of course the case $p = 2$ is just one half of the Ito isometry. For $p > 2$ with $M_t = \int_0^t X_t\,dW_t$,

$$\phi(M_t) = \phi(M_T) + \int_0^t \phi'(M_t)\,dM_t + \frac 1 2 \int_0^t \phi''(M_t)\,d\langle M \rangle_t,$$

by Itos formula, where $\phi(x) = |x|^p$.

Then,

$$|M_T|^p = p \int_0^T |M|^{p-2}X\,dW + \frac{p(p-2)}{2}\int_0^T |M_t|^{p-2} X_t^2\,dt + \int_0^T \frac p 2 |M_t|^{p-2} X_t^2\,dt.$$

While the first summand may not have expectation zero (because it is not necessarily a martingale), it does have expectation zero if stopped at appropiate stopping times, i.e.
$$\tau_n := \inf \{t\geq 0 : |M_t|\geq n\}.$$

For simplicity I'm going to assume the expectation is zero (for the real proof you have to carry along $\tau_n$ and then let $n\to \infty$ at the end).

Hölder's inequality then shows

$$\mathbb E|M_T|^p \leq \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \|\int_0^T|X_t|^2\|_{p/2} \|\int_0^T |M_t|^p\|_{\frac p {p-2}} = \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |X_t|^p\,dt\right)^{2/p}\left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |M_t|^p\,dt\right)^{\frac {p-2} p}.$$

But then $(|M_t|^p)_{t\geq 0}$ is a submartingale, so $\mathbb E|M_T|^p \geq \mathbb E|M_t|^p$ and

$$\mathbb E\int_0^T |M_t|^p\,dt \leq T \mathbb E|M_T|^p.$$

Therefore,

$$\mathbb E|M_T|^p \leq \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |X_t|^p\,dt\right)^{2/p}(T \mathbb E|M_T|^p)^{\frac {p-2} p},$$

and dividing by $(\mathbb E|M_T|^p)^{\frac {p-2} p}$ and then taking the square root yields

$$\|M_T\|_p = (\mathbb E|M_T|^p)^{(1 - \frac{p-2} p)/2} \leq \left(\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\right)^{1/2} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |X_t|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}T^{\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 p}.$$

In your case

$$\|\int_0^T f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)\,dW_t\|_p \leq \sqrt{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}}T^{\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 p} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p} < \epsilon \sqrt{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}T}.$$

Comment: It seems like you bounded the $\mathcal{p}$-norm of $\| \int f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)dt\|$, wasn't it supposed to be the $\mathcal{p}$-norm of $\| \int f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)dW_t\|$ ?

Comment: @Kate Fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the line under "Holder's inequality then shows". Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: You apply Hölder's inequality for a different kind of $p$-norm for stochastic processes given by $\|X\|_p := \left(\mathbb E \int_0^T |X_t|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}$. Under this norm, $\| X^2 |M|^{p-2}| \|_1 \leq \| X^2 \|_{p/2} \| |M|^{p-2} \|_{\frac p {p-2}}$ since $1/(p/2) + 1/(p/(p-2)) = 1$.

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain how you got this line  $\|\int_0^T f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)\,dW_t\|_p \leq \sqrt{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}}T^{\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 p} \left(\mathbb E\int_0^T |f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)|^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}$

Comment: Sure. Do you agree with the line "From this the inequality easily follows."? If so, then use this inequality and set the "$X_t$" to $f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)$.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. I should have asked I don't see how the inequality follows. In the last line I see that you plugged in $f(X_t) - f^*(X_t)$

Comment: @Kate I added some details.

Comment: Now I see, big thanks! The norm you used $\|  X\|_p  = (\mathbb{E} \int |X_t|^p dt)^{1/p}$ Is it a standard norm used in stochastic calculus?

Comment: @Kate It is the ordinary $p$-norm, except on the space $L_p(\Omega \times [0,T])$ with measure $\mathbb P \otimes \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.
- and yes, it occurs often, e.g., with $p = 2$, as expectation of quadratic variation of Ito processes. The case $p = 2$ is certainly the most popular one.